R Data Manipulation Help: For each value in column B, look in column A for the "best match" and set value to that value
I am doing some genetics work and I am trying to utilize two data sets, however each one refers to the genes differently. One dataset (lets call it Column A) refers to each gene by its conventional name as well as a specific ID. The other data set uses some combination of those two variables. I'd rather not have to rerun the pipeline to get the names to align, so I was hoping I could match and copy values as per the title. To reiterate, I was hoping that for each value in column B, look in column A for the "best match" and set value to that value.
Below is an example of the columns and my issues



Column A
Column B




gene1-ID001
gene1


gene2-ID002
ID002


gene3-ID003
gene3-ID003


gene4-ID004
gene4



The desired output is as follows:



Column A
Column B




gene1-ID001
gene1-ID001


gene2-ID002
gene2-ID002


gene3-ID003
gene3-ID003


gene4-ID004
gene4-ID004



The names/gene IDs in each data set are tied to different values and are not arranged in a specific order.
Happy to learn about any established tools for these kinds of issues as well. Thanks you.
I'm fairly certain I need to use grep in some manner to check for partial matches before setting values, but the finesse in setting this up is something I'm lacking. Handling issues when there are more than one partial matches and picking the "most matching" is a problem.

When you say you have two data sets does that mean those columns A and B are from different tables?

Include the output that you want

Normalize the names in column B. For instance, you could put all the unique names from Column A into a list (list_A), and then for each name in column B (name_B), and then use grep: grep(name_B, list_A). This will give you the list of indexes in list_A that contain name_B. If it's unique, keep it. Otherwise, produce an error and resolve the ambiguity by hand.

Addressing comments in order:
Yes, they are gene identifiers from two different data sets.
I've edited to include the output.
These data sets are massive with thousands of entries, so manual curation of edge cases is not feasible.

@awsk check the solution below

You could use agrep with max distance of 0.
df$C = df[sapply(df[[2]], agrep, df[[1]], max.distance = 0),1]
df
     Column_A    Column_B           C
1 gene1-ID001       gene1 gene1-ID001
2 gene2-ID002       ID002 gene2-ID002
3 gene3-ID003 gene3-ID003 gene3-ID003
4 gene4-ID004       gene4 gene4-ID004


You can use adist with partial matching:
df$C <- df[max.col(-adist(df[[2]], df[[1]], partial = TRUE)), 1]
df

     Column_A    Column_B           C
1 gene1-ID001       gene1 gene1-ID001
2 gene2-ID002       ID002 gene2-ID002
3 gene3-ID003 gene3-ID003 gene3-ID003
4 gene4-ID004       gene4 gene4-ID004


Thank you for the answer! I am trying your first implementation and am assuredly misunderstanding some basic syntax here. I tried to set it up between two data frames, but it is not changing the first column of test2m.
test1 <- c("gene1-ID001", "gene2-ID002", "gene3-ID003") test1exp <- c(5, 12, 13) test2 <- c("gene1", "ID002", "gene3-ID003") test2exp <- c(6, 13, 15) test1m <- as.data.frame(cbind(test1,test1exp)) test2m <- as.data.frame(cbind(test2,test2exp)) test2m$test2 <- test2m[sapply(test2m[[1]], agrep, test1m[[1]], max.distance = 0) ,1]

@awsk first do not use as.data.frame(cbind(...)) that changes the datatype. Use dataframe(...).  Second, you are using test2m[sapply...] instead of test1m[sapply..]

Thanks Onyambu, the swap to test1m worked for the test examples, and I think I understand why that's important.
I'm moving to trying to employ it for my actual data and running into some issues. These are S4 objects, and the slots I'm referencing contain the gene names as described. Again, I apologize for my lack of experience with the syntax here, but where am I going wrong? Running:
scRNAgenes@Dimnames[[1]] <- spatialgenes@Dimnames[[1]][sapply(scRNAgenes@Dimnames[[1]], agrep, spatialgenes@Dimnames[[1]], max.distance = 0)]
I get an invalid subscript type "list" error
